# Salinity affecting Plant Growth

Tags: database, experiment-design, biostatistics

I conducted an experiment where I treated 9 bean seeds to different levels of salinity (ranging from 0g to 4g of salt) when watering them, in order to determine whether if salinity affected seed growth. After watering them fro 10 days, I measured the mass of each of the seeds and determined that the mass of seeds generally decreased as the salinity increased. However since I have 9 data sets, I I cannot conduct the T-test to determine whether if salinity has an affect on seed grwoth. Is there any other statistical test I could conduct in this situation?

Comment: A note on terms:  it would be standard to say you have 9 observations or 9 cases.  All your data constitute a single data set.

Answer (score 1):

The most natural choice for this experiment is [linear regression](http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/regintro.htm).

If you had data from several beans for each salinity level, [one factor ANOVA](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/analysis_of_variance/intro.html) could be useful, too.